# how to add an arrow in a drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a working simple **jquery drop-down menu**. But problem is **how can I put an arrow** or just '+' character each other like other usual menus if list has sub-menu, of course.

```
function Mx_menu(){
    $(".menu ul").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
    $(".menu li").hover(function(){
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(400);
            },function(){
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });

}    

    $(document).ready(function(){                   
        Mx_menu();
    });
```

And CSS file here:

```
.menu, .menu ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; list-style-position:outside; position:relative; }
.menu a { color:#a6a6a6; display:block; padding:6px 10px; }             
.menu li { float:left; position:relative; width:200px; }
.menu ul { position:absolute; display:none; width:200px; top:0; left:200px; }
.menu li ul a { width:200px; height:auto; float:left; }
.menu ul ul { top:auto; }
.menu li ul ul { left:200px; margin:0; }
.menu li:hover ul ul, .menu li:hover ul ul ul, .menu li:hover ul ul ul ul { display:none; }
.menu li:hover ul, .menu li li:hover ul, .menu li li li:hover ul, .menu li li li li:hover ul { display:block; }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a plain old `select` node instead?

Comment: I didn't get. Actually I need to add an arrow to current list if that list has submenu.

Comment: @Delan - `<select>` doesn't have child menus (possibly many levels), re-read the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution, so it's called: prev():

```
$(".menu li ul").prev().css("background", "url(IMG_URL) transparent");
```

Final jquery code here:

```
function Mx_menu(){

    $(".menu li ul").prev().css("background", "url('IMG_URL')");

    $(".menu ul").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
    $(".menu li").hover(function(){
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(400);

            },function(){
                $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
}   
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    Mx_menu();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple like this to prepend a `+` (or whatever ASCII character) just before the child `<ul>` that's inside the `<li>` using [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/), like this:

```
$(".menu li ul").before(' +');
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QHQaq/)

Comment: thank you nick, but before isn't enough for complex solutions. I found prev(). Check this, and it works:

$(".menu li ul").prev().css("background", "url('IMG URL') transparent");

Comment: @beytar - I'm glad you found a solution, it's not the question you asked though...you asked how to insert a character, not add a background image...make sure to ask for what you're *actually* after in future questions :)

Comment: I think it's OK. But let say I was so happy when I found prev() as much as rediscover jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu li:hover ul li { background:transparent url( IMG_PATH ) left center no-repeat; padding-left:12px; }
```

Note the lack of support for the pseudo-selector of li, in IE6.